# False "new entity found through the relationship" - Object actually exists in database

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, orm, symfony4

We have a service which purpose is to log user actions into database. The underlying entity *ActionLog* has a *manyToOne* relation with our *User* entity. Both those entities are tied to the same DBAL connection (and ORM EntityManager).

**Issue is**: an exception is raised when a new *ActionLog* entity is persisted and flushed, saying we should cascade persist the object set as the *#user* property because considered new:

> **A new entity was found** through the relationship 'Doctrine\Model\ActionLog#user' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: John Doe. To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}).

And this is annoying because the User instance actually comes straight from the database and as such isn't new at all! We expect this User object to already be ["MANAGED"](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/unitofwork.html#how-doctrine-keeps-track-of-objects) by the *entityManager* and be [referenced through the *identity map*](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/unitofwork.html#how-doctrine-keeps-track-of-objects) (in other words, the object is not "detached").

---

**So**, why would Doctrine consider the User entity instance (authenticated user) as detached/new?

---

*Using Symfony 4.0.6 ; doctrine/orm v2.6.1, doctrine/dbal 2.6.3, doctrine/doctrine-bundle 1.8.1*

**ActionLog** model mapping extract

```
Doctrine\Model\ActionLog:
    type: entity
    table: action_log
    repositoryClass: Doctrine\Repository\ActionLogRepository

    manyToOne:
        user:
            targetEntity: Doctrine\Model\User
    id: # …
    fields: # …
```

**Log service declaration**

```
log_manager:
    class: Service\Log\LogManager
    public: true
    arguments:
        - "@?security.token_storage"
    calls:
        # setter required instead of the dependency injection
        # to prevent circular dependency.
        - ['setEntityManager', ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]]
```

**Log service implementation - Creates new ActionLog record**

```
<?php

namespace Service\Log;

use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Doctrine\Model\User;
use Doctrine\Model\ActionLog;

class LogManager
{
    /**
     * @var ObjectManager
     */
    protected $om;

    /**
     * @var TokenStorage
     */
    protected $tokenStorage;

    /**
     * @var User
     */
    protected $user;

    /**
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $disabled = false;

    public function __construct(TokenStorage $tokenStorage = null)
    {
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
    }

    public function setEntityManager(ObjectManager $om)
    {
        $this->om = $om;
    }

    public function log(string $namespace, string $action, string $message = null, array $changeSet = null)
    {
        $log = new ActionLog;
        $log
            ->setNamespace($namespace)
            ->setAction($action)
            ->setMessage($message)
            ->setChangeset($changeSet)
        ;

        if ($this->isDisabled()) {
            return;
        }

        if (!$log->getUser()) {
            $user = $this->getUser();
            $log->setUsername(
                $user instanceof UserInterface
                ? $user->getUsername()
                : ''
            );
            $user instanceof User && $log->setUser($user);
        }

        $this->om->persist($log);
        $this->om->flush();
    }

    public function setUser(User $user): self
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUser(): ?UserInterface
    {
        if (!$this->user) {
            if ($token = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()) {
                $this->user = $token->getUser();
            }
        }

        return is_string($this->user) ? null : $this->user;
    }

    public function disable(bool $disabled = true): self
    {
        $this->disabled = $disabled;

        return $this;
    }

    public function isDisabled(): bool
    {
        return $this->disabled;
    }
}
```

**User entity dump**. As you can see infos come from the database.

```
User {#417 ▼
  #name: "John Doe"
  #email: "john_doe@example.com"
  #password: "ec40577ad8057ee34ce0bb9414673bf3"
  #createdAt: DateTime @1523344938 {#427 ▶}
  #enabled: true
  #lastLogin: null
  #id: 1
}

# Associated database row
'1', 'John Doe', 'john_doe@example.com', 'ec40577ad8057ee34ce0bb9414673bf3', '2018-04-10 07:22:18', '1', '1', null
```

Comment: Did you try to add `inversedBy`, `mappedBy` and `joinColumn`on the mapping association ? https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html

Comment: @UgoT. No I did not, because ActionLog is the owning side of the relation and there is no reason for _User_ entity instances to be able to reach any associated ActionLogs (There might be dozen).

Comment: All right, if you don't want to use `*By` tags you have to create a join table. According the [doc](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-unidirectional-with-join-table), a unidirectional oneToMany is nothing else than a ManyToMany relation  with a unique constraint on one of the join columns.

Comment: Why would I need an extra join table either? This is nothing but a simple manyToOne relation. The_ActionLog_ table holds a reference to a `User` instance (in other words a foreign key) that's all `:|` The _oneToMany_ would be relevant in case I needed the User entity to fetch associated `ActionLog` records (user would be the inverse side in this case) but once again I don't need this behavior.

Comment: Okay, I'm sorry, I've misread your relation. I was just blocked on the relation onetToMany while it was a manyToOne in your code... Sorry for taking your time.

Comment: Seems `if (!$log->getUser())` always will be true, so `user` comes from session, hence exception on detached/new entity. Try `$this->om->refresh($user)` before persist.

Comment: Do you mean the user object is reconstructed from a serialized session object and not retrieved from database ?

Comment: Yep, exactly. You might need reload it before save the log entity.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting, I will change my code, do some tests and let you know.

Comment: Otherwise, use DBAL, faster and avoiding the reload query.

Answer (score 2):

**The assert was right**, the *User* instance being passed to `ActionLog::setUser` method was not a known reference from the ORM point of view.
**What happens:** the object comes from the authentication process which unserialize the *User* data from session storage on each request (what suggested *yceruto*) and a *User* instance is created.
**My custom  userProvider should refresh the user** object via the ORM but it doesn't, hence the "new reference" upon *persist*. I have no idea why although my UserProvider implementation lets suppose it should:

```
/**
 * @var ObjectManager
 */
protected $em;

public function __construct(ObjectManager $em)
{
    $this->em = $em;
}

public function loadUserByUsername($username)
{
    $user = $this->em->getRepository(User::class)->loadUserByUsername($username);

    if ($user && $user->isAdmin()) {
        return $user;
    }

    throw new UsernameNotFoundException(
        sprintf('Username "%s" does not exist.', $username)
    );
}

public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
{
    return $this->loadUserByUsername($user->getUsername());
}

public function supportsClass($class)
{
    return UserInterface::class === $class;
}
```

**This said, I managed to (temporarily) solve the issue** using the [ORM proxy mechanism](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/advanced-configuration.html#reference-proxies) with the help of the `Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::getReference` method, this can be done since the rebuilt object from session holds the User id (primary key).

The fix consist in replacing the following instruction in the Log_manager service:

```
$this->user = $token->getUser();
# ↓ BECOMES ↓
$this->user = $this->om->getReference(User::class, $token->getUser()->getId());
```

---

Any idea on this? Misuse? Github issue?  *Whatever the reason, comments are quite welcome.*

Comment: That also implies that there is a custom user provider somewhere since, out of the box, the Doctrine EntityUserProvider will always reload the user on each request.  Adjusting the provider will make the need for user references go away.

Comment: @Cerad right, I have a _user provider_ (service), assigned to the security config key `security:providers:appusers:id` in security.yaml, plus the `appusers` is used as `security:firewalls:main:provider` value. I agree on the fact that the _provider_ is supposed to refresh the user via `refreshUser()` method, but it seems the user isn't refreshed, although the provider implementation refresh process do query the EntityManager to retrive it from database: `$this->em->getRepository(User::class)->loadUserByUsername($username);`. I don't get why the user still not being refreshed…

Comment: Hmmm.  Multiple entity managers?  Do you see the query in the profiler bar?  Possibly someone got fancy with a Doctrine cache?  If the user provider is your code then I suppose you could explicitly merge the user.  But it all seems very strange.

Comment: We have multiple managers, but Doctrine defaults to the right one. From the log service, calling `$this->om->contains($this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser())` returns `false`. Calling `$this->om->getConnection()->getDatabase()` returns the right manager (name).

Comment: With multiple managers then might be best to just to do your reference thing.

Comment: @Cerad I made my answer a bit clearer, maybe something will come to mind once you have looked at my custom userProvider implementation.

Comment: I assume you are certain that the logger is using the same entity manager as the user provider?  Having a different entity manager for logging is not unusual.  Might take a look at how the entity manager's are being injected.  And of course it is possible that some jolly joking code is resetting your entity manager.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, that's right I'm pretty sure about this given: entityManagers are instanciated as _singletons_ and the entityManager name retrived from the logManager matches the one caught within the userProvider. I will triple check...